# jquery fade out div with page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, scrolltop

I am trying to fade a div out as the page scrolls down (with the page scroll - not just a fadeOut effect). I'm adjusting the opacity of the div as the page scrolls down using this piece of code here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.logo_container').css({'opacity':( 100-scroll )/100});
});
```

My issue here is that for me it fades out too fast, I'd like a much more subtle fade as the user scrolls. Can anyone think of a better logic to make a slower, more subtle fade out.

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2k3hfwo0/) showing my code in action

Comment: I made an update of your jsfiddle, maybe this is better? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k3hfwo0/1/)

Comment: Yeah that's really nice. What led you to use those figures - or was it just trial and error?

Comment: Just a bit trial and error, tweaking your fiddle a bit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2k3hfwo0/3/ this? calculated by half of the window height

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes that is actually perfect - great idea using the window height - I changed it slightly to use the parent container height

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/0ma4na3t/

Answer (score 17):

This works fine with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0ma4na3t/1/) with very simple logic.
Used this piece of jquery to make it work:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('.logo_container, .slogan').css({
        'opacity': ((height - scrollTop) / height)
    }); 
});
```

> **(height - scrollTop) / height** gives value set which is **linear form 1 to 0.**

Example:

height=430px and scrollTop=233px.

(height - scrollTop) / height will give opacity 0.45 approx.

Comment: If i did not want this to go to 0 or fade out completely how would i set it so it only fades to .3?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution A

jQuery animate

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.logo_container, .slogan').stop().animate(
        {opacity: (( 180-scroll )/100)+0.1},
        "slow"
    );
});
```

## Solution B

CSS transition

```
.wrapper {
    height:1000px
}
.logo_container {
    background:red;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

improved the solution by changing that part `( 1000-scroll )/1000`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2k3hfwo0/9/)

hope it helps